# Sometimes gyroscope provides strange values on Android

Tags: android, rotation, gyroscope

I am developing an Android app to analyse the location, rotation and acceleration data provided by the Android sensors while driving in the car. Therefore I implemented one service for the GPS location updates and one service for the values given by the gyroscope and accelerometer.

Furthermore I converted the values given by the Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE to the DIN70000 coordinate system. Based on the results I do my data analysis.

On my evaluations I realized that sometimes the values  become strange and unexpected. Next time (same device) they are normal again.

**Normal data:**

11.67,9.29,3.61,1.76 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

-2.46,-1.6,-2.76,-10.21 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

-13.48,-11.16,-13.9,4.16 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

-11.85,-3.85,-7.21,3.48 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

0,-4.58,-3.85,-5.13,-5.07 (5 samples in row for rotation x)

**Strange data:**

210.9,210.9,0,0 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

0,0,-118.91,-118.91,319.43,0 (6 samples in row for rotation x)

0,266.97,123.56,71.24 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

167.87,167.87,-98.02,-98.02,143.37,143.37 (6 samples in row for rotation x)

229.73,0,174.19,285.57 (4 samples in row for rotation x)

I am pretty sure that I did not perfomed driving maneuvers like a 360 with my car to produce such data. The data stay in this erroneous state from starting till stopping the app. Often the values seem to be occuring in pairs.
I did a lot of test drives and the values are wrong for over 60% of the drives.
Also I tested on different devices with different Android versions and also here the same problem occured with more or less incidence.

Did someone else experienced the same behaviour of the gyrosope sensor?
Is there a way to trigger a re-calibration?

I am realy looking forward for your response because I was not able to reproduce it at the desk and it it realy hard to track.